# Cannot get FuelPHP action to run

Tags: php, url-rewriting, fuelphp

I'm new to FuelPHP and I did a little coding with it! What I did was create a simple controller and created two methods. One for action_index() and the other is action_add().
the code is given below. Views are already in the app\views\ folder.

```
 class Controller_Student extends Controller
{
    public function action_index()
    {
        return Response::forge(View::forge('index'));
    }

    public function action_add()
    {
        return Response::forge(View::forge('select'));
    }
}
```

I've set the root to this controller class. When I run the application the index works fine and loads the directed view. But when I give the following URL

```
 http://localhost/project/public/add/
```

the method doesn't get called! A 404 error is give saying

```
 You can see this page because the URL you are accessing cannot be found.
```

What Am I doing wrong here. I've gone through every documentation, tutorial I find but I shouldn't get this type of an error. Please help me.

Below is the routing file code :

```
   return array(
'_root_'  => 'student',  // The default route
'_404_'   => 'welcome/404',    // The main 404 route
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the root to `student` controller, but that doesn't mean all traffic goes through that controller.  Try visiting:
`http://localhost/project/public/student/add/`

Comment: you are the man! :D Can you explain me what this routing is all about! it would help me a lot!

Comment: http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/routing.html can explain better than I can.  You can think of `_root_` in this case as the home page.  You've set it to a controller, so it defaults to the `index` action.  You could have set it to `student/bob/joe/phil`, or any number of things, it bares absolutely no relation to any other routes other than `/`.  There are ways to route everything through one controller, but it is very much discouraged.  Glad it's sorted